# AngularJS filtering - multiple expressions or dynamically chain ng-filters?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If you take a look at the code below, I'd like to use a text `<input>` to filter each menu item by multiple ingredients - for example, if the user typed "beef, bacon" into the `<input>`, the app would return ALL menu items with beef OR bacon as an ingredient.

I'm currently trying to do this using ng-filter, and I'm guessing I need to create a custom filter in order to this. Is this the wrong approach?? Is there a way to dynamically chain filters instead?

Here's some code which should make sense of my problem -

**My search model:**
*- Note: using ng-list to turn string into an array of substrings*

```
<div ng-init="searchString=[]">
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchString" ng-list>
</div>
```

**My ng-repeat loop:**
*- Note: using a custom filter to join each of my ingredient into one string*

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in menu | filter:{ category : 'Classics' } | filter:{ ingredients : searchString } ">
    <td class="title">{{ item.title }}</td>
    <td class="ingredients">
        {{ item.ingredients | join:', ' }}
    </td>
    <td class="price">{{ item.price | currency }}</td>
</tr>
```

**My data structure**

```
$scope.menu = [
    {
        "title" : "New Yorker",
        "price" : "4.00",
        "ingredients" : [
            "Salt Beef",
            "Pickles",
            "Mustard"
        ],
        "category" : "Classics"
    },
    {
        "title" : "BLT",
        "price" : "4.00",
        "ingredients" : [
            "Bacon",
            "Lettuce",
            "Tomato"
        ],
        "category" : "Classics"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

(I get that this is probably a dead question, but I found it too so:)

A custom filter is needed because you want to filter menu items that share at least one ingredient with your search list (i.e. non-empty array intersection). The filter used in the question, `filter:{ ingredients : searchString }` does not filter that way, nor do any of the other filters built into Angular from their [official doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

Creating a custom filter is easy; Add a new function `containsIngredientsFromSearch` to the `$scope`:

```
 // Filter functions are called separately for each item on the menu
$scope.containsIngredientsFromSearch = function(menuItem){     
  // Check every ingredient on the search list ...
  for(var i in $scope.searchString) {
    var ingredient = $scope.searchString[i];
    // ... does it match an ingredient in menuItem.ingredients?
    if(menuItem.ingredients.indexOf(ingredient) !== -1) {
      // ... if so, stop searching and return true to include this menuItem
      return true;
    }
  }

  // No matching ingredient found? Return false to exclude this item.
  return false;
}
```

Add the filter to the existing filter chain:

`<tr ng-repeat="item in menu | filter:{ category : 'Classics' } | filter:containsIngredientsFromSearch">`

See it in action [on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/xucuciyi/1/edit?html,output).

Answer (score 1):

you can create a custom filter, or use a angular filter with a predicate (a function)

```
{ filter_expression | filter:predicateFunction }}
```

of course, your function lives in your controller's scope, where the search string is visible

> A predicate function can be used to write arbitrary filters. The
>   function is called for each element of array. The final result is an
>   array of those elements that the predicate returned true for.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter